# Clickhouse - create a column which tags dates to a predefined dynamic range

Tags: grouping, clickhouse

In clickhouse, I'm trying to create a new column which 'groups' dates together. I have two tables, one with the main data and the second with logic of how the dates should be grouped, if the date in table A is less than or equal to the date in table B then it should be B's date bucket (see image attached; was manually made so hope no errors)

[image]

I'm trying to write this in an environment where CTEs are not supported and I have no write access to create tables or temp tables.

I see two possible solutions
a) Expand table B to have every single date and corresponding bucket then do a join
b) Do a join where you filter table B for the 'nearest' value then join

Didnt get far with both solutions

Comment: Does your dates in table B mean something? Like bi weekly dates or end of the month?

Comment: Hi - Dates in table B are like events dates which can be treat static, there is no predefined logic e.g every 2 or X weeks or days.